# Geometry Nodes: How to instantiate Feathers along Cylinder circumference and Z Axis?

Tags: modeling, node-editor, transforms, weight-painting, geometry-nodes

Currently I have a few rows of feathers around a cylinder. I want to be able to:

- A. Identify the origin of the cylinder and rotate each feather
  outwards
- B. Create rows of different feather sets along the Z axis, unrestricted to the cylinder's side segments (considering offsetting,
  concentration falloff/weight and organic shapes in the future)

How to achieve it using geometry nodes?[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

be aware that the top and bottom normals and not pointing to the side (as you might hope)

Answer (score 0):

With a base feather facing -Y/+Y, like this:

[image]

A possibility is to use several circles, along a line, then,

- get a first rotation so that all feather are facing each circle center: `atan2(y, x)` makes so all instances have the same orientation relative to the center, and adding `pi / 2` because of -Y/+Y starting orientation
- combine with a second rotation to align Z of instances to normals (with the degree you want, using the factor input)

[image]